# What is the benefit of using vagrant in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, laravel-5, wamp, homestead

What is the benefit of using Vagrant (via [homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead)) instead of using WAMP server on Microsoft Windows?

I found that configuring homestead and vagrant is harder than installing WAMP. Isn't it?

Comment: Your question is more about Vagrant than Laravel, take a look at: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/why-vagrant/

Comment: Homestead will deliver identical environments for multiple developers working in the same application. So if you are on Linux, Mac or Windows, your application couldn't care less as long as it is running within homestead.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Vagrant is a homestead for development environment.

Its easy to install server requirements and including many dependencies in out command.

```
Ubuntu 14.04
PHP 5.6
HHVM
Nginx
MySQL
Postgres
Node (With Bower, Grunt, and Gulp)
Redis
Memcached
Beanstalkd
Laravel Envoy
Fabric + HipChat Extension
```

You don't needs to spend your time for configuring web server locally for this.

I think in windows better is Wamp, but in case of Ububtu and Mac, the Vagrant (Homestead) is better than others...

Comment: I think you really should do some more reasearch about Vagrant, because that is not the real benefit of using Vagrant.